# Uniquely combining 3 lists into 1 with dictionary comprehension in Python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am new to learning Python and I'm a few 100s lines of code in!

```
start = ['12', '08', '07', '16', '04']
middle = ['01', '01', '01', '01', '01']
end = ['13', '07', '08', '15', '05']
```

Desired output (in order):

```
[('1201': '13'), ('0801': '07'), ('0701': '08'), ('1601': '15'), ('0401', '05')]
```

The below code will fail to keep the original order (I'm stuck using python 3.4 and know 3.7+ would resolve this)

```
Combined_Lists = {start+middle: end for start, middle, end in zip(start, middle, end)}
```

When I try the below, it errors

```
from collections import OrderedDict
Combined_Lists = {start+middle: end for start, middle, end in OrderedDict(zip(start, middle, end))}
```

error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: you could also just do a integer loop in the comprehension.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `zip` is producing 3 values, but `OrderedDict` requires an iterable of `(key, value)` pairs.

```
od = OrderedDict((s+m, e) for s, m, e in zip(start, middle, end))
```

You can't unpack this into a regular dictionary afterwards because then you will lose the order.

Your desired output is a list, so you might be looking for

```
[(s+m, e) for s, m, e in zip(start, middle, end)]
```

instead.

Comment: 3.5 hours on this today and you saved my Sunday!  Having to learn this stuff in my non-work time, wanting to be a Sys Developer!!  Thank you very much, if I could tip you $10, I would.  Thanks--signed some sys engineer